# Line break or "\n" is not working.

Tags: python, line-breaks

Could you tell me why the line break \n isn't working?

```
itemsToWriteToFile = "Number 1:", 12, "\nNumber 2: ", 13, "\nNumber 3: ", 13, "\nNumber 4: ", 14
itemsToWriteToFile = str(itemsToWriteToFile)

itemsToWriteToFile = itemsToWriteToFile.replace('(', "")
itemsToWriteToFile = itemsToWriteToFile.replace(')', "")
itemsToWriteToFile = itemsToWriteToFile.replace('"', "")
itemsToWriteToFile = itemsToWriteToFile.replace(',', "")
itemsToWriteToFile = itemsToWriteToFile.replace('\n', "")

print(itemsToWriteToFile)
```

Comment: Why are you converting a tuple of strings and ints to a string in the first place?  What's your goal here?

Comment: OH, sorry... totally saw this come up in a JS tag. (deleting original comment).

Comment: DSM, the code is editted slightly from my original program, so it makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `str()` transformation is converting the "\n" into "\\n".

```
>>> str('\n')
'\n'
>>> str(['\n'])
"['\\n']"
```

What's going on there? When you call `str()` on a list (same for tuple), that will call the `__str__()` method of the list, which in turn calls `__repr__()` on each of its elements. Let's check what its behaviour is:

```
>>> "\n".__str__()
'\n'
>>> "\n".__repr__()
"'\\n'"
```

So there you have the cause.

As for how to fix it, like Blender proposed, the best option would be to not use `str()` on the list:

```
''.join(str(x) for x in itemsToWriteToFile)
```

Comment: Why does it add a second "\" when using str() ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. As to the behaviour of str.__repr__, I couldn't find any reference explaining it, but it kind of makes sense in that you want to visualize the content of the string, not the actual string.

Comment: This is incorrect. You shouldn't have to replace these in the first place.

Comment: The question asks why OP's code isn't working, and that's what I've answered.

Comment: This answer is what I was looking for; the others are useful tips.

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers are fixing a problem that shouldn't even exist. Translate your tuple of strings and ints into just a list of strings. Then, use `str.join()` to join them together into one big string:

```
foo = "Number 1:", 12, "\nNumber 2: ", 13, "\nNumber 3: ", 13, "\nNumber 4: ", 14
bar = map(str, foo)

print(''.join(bar))
```

Comment: I see what you have done there. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: This answer is nice to have, but I wouldn't say it is better than Siegfried's. I googled "python newline not working" and got this question. An optimization on OP's code is meaningless to me, and I suspect to most people. It's much more useful to know that `str('\n')` returns `'\n'`.

Comment: @gwg: It's not an optimization. If you want to join things together, use `str.join()`. (Ab)using `str(itemsToWriteToFile)` and then removing the parentheses, commas, and quotes is just the wrong way to do it. It's like using `eval(str(a) + ' * ' + str(b))` to multiply two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
itemsToWriteToFile = itemsToWriteToFile.translate(None, "(),\"\\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itemsToWriteToFile.replace('\\n', "")` instead of  `itemsToWriteToFile.replace('\n', "")`

```
>>itemsToWriteToFile = itemsToWriteToFile.replace('\\n', "")

Final Output:-

>>> print(itemsToWriteToFile)
'Number 1:' 12 'Number 2: ' 13 'Number 3: ' 13 'Number 4: ' 14
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and I solved it by making the following changes:

1. Changing my Charfield to a TextField in my model
2. Adding the model to my admin panel so that when editting the field I could press [Enter] manually in the value instead of using '\n'

Then using {{value|linebreaks}} finally worked. Guess \n in the string didnt work because of Sigfried's answer above.