# Evalute Escaped Characters When Writing to Files

Tags: python

To my understanding, Python will escape escaped characters when reading values from a file. For example, the newline character `\n` will become `\\n`.

However, when I am writing into an output file I want a newline instead of printing `\n`.

Code example:

```
output_file = open(os.path.join(path, file), 'a')

value1 = "abcd"
value2 = "1234"
delimiter = "\\n"                                 # in reality not hardcoded

output_file.write(value1 + delimiter + value2)
output_file.close()
```

I want this to show up as:

```
abcd
1234
```

While it's currently showing as:

```
abcd\n1234
```

While it's possible to do a `replace()`, I want to avoid this because delimiter may be ANY escaped value. (ie. I don't want the following):

```
.replace('\\n', '\n').replace('\\t', '\t')...
```

Edit:

The file reading example is as follows:

```
try:
    with open(input_data, 'r') as input:
        for line in input:
        ...
        key,value = line.split('=', 1)
        ...
        if (key.strip() == 'delimiter'):       # in reality done through loop
            index_dict['delimiter'] = value
```

and the file contains:

```
delimiter="\n"
```

Comment: Have you tried simply `replace('\\\\', '\\')`?

Comment: could you provide an example of python escaping characters when reading values from a file? I don't think python read newline as `\\n`

Comment: My guess is that it's doing a str() cast when iterating through the file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067781/line-break-or-n-is-not-working

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python isn't escaping anything coming from your data file. The backslash character (and the quotation marks) are actually in the file text. It sounds like you want to evaluate the string after you read it, so that rather than `value` being `'"\\n"'` (a string with double quotes around a backslash and an "n" character), you get `'\n'`(a string with a single newline character).

I suggest using `ast.literal_eval`. It works similar to the builtin `eval` function, but won't ever call functions or do other dangerous stuff, while `eval` might. In addition to strings it will also evaluate other kinds of Python literals (e.g. `int`, `float` and `complex` numbers, and containers like `list`, `tuple`, `set` and `dict` (as long as the contents of the containers are also literals).

```
if (key.strip() == 'delimiter'):
    index_dict['delimiter'] = ast.literal_eval(value)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a perfect answer. Not only did you address the root of the problem but you also expanded my understanding of the Python language. Up until now, I've only been using ast.literal_eval to expand flattened dictionaries. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `delimiter` variable from `"\\n"` to `"\n"`, that should fix it.

EDIT: This question will help you solve your problem, look at the accepted answer for an example.

[Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: When you get it, just say `if delimiter == '\\n': delimiter = '\n'`. easy.

Comment: It's not only newline. If I was only targeting newline, a simple .replace('\\n', '\n') would fix it.

Comment: You'll be better off finding out why your data is coming in with double blackslashes and rectify that instead. This is a huge problem because single backslashes are not valid literals so you can't really manipulate them...